# How to get all email contacts from my gmail accounts?

Tags: android, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, android-contacts

I am implementing an app which need to get all emails contacts from current google email account . 
I researched on this link below but it did not help.

[https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes](http://GMAIL%20API)

I synced google email account to device contacts phone and then get all contacts phone but still can not see. Is there any way to get it ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to go though the [Google people api](https://developers.google.com/people/)

The People API lets you list and manage the authenticated user's Contacts and retrieve profile information for authenticated users and their contacts.

The Gmail api just contains emails.